# Why is writeValue not returning a Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, web-bluetooth

I'm working on mocking the process of writing data to a Web Bluetooth device. I've run into an issue where [`.writeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic/writeValue) is not returning a promise.

Can somebody either let me know why this isn't working or how I can essentially replace this method to return a promise, I'm not wanting to test the functionality of a depreciated method at the end of the day.

```js
const str2ab = (value: string) => {
  // string to array buffer
} 

let chunk = "my message";

let txCharacteristic: BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic;

txCharacteristic
    .writeValue(str2ab(chunk))
    .then(function(){
        // do something
    })
```

I've attempted to see if I can find a way to override this method but have had no luck.

To expand on this the error im receiving is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

*as for the method being depreciated I know, currently I'm just working from a spec and don't have say in changing it.*

Comment: When you say not returning a promise, what exactly is happening?

Comment: Im receiving an error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

Comment: Are you seeing this in a mocked environment, or in production? Is there a reason you're sticking with `writeValue` when your linked MDN docs note its deprecation (and that it may stop working at any time)?

Comment: @JeffBowman This is coming from a mocked environment

Comment: @cllmmclu Please post the mock implementation then, which appears to be the culprit